# PowerShell error while saving an opened Excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to save and close an opened Excel document with PowerShell code, but it returns me a read-only error.

System is Windows Server 2012, but I tried in Windows 10 too.
tried this

```
$a = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$a.Visible = $True
$a.DisplayAlerts = $False 
$b = $a.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Users\john\Desktop\doc.xlsx", [System.Type]::Missing, $false ) 
$b.Save()
$b.Close()
```

but remains opened and changes not saved

Comment: Use SaveAs only if you use a different name. In you case use "$b.Save()".

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, this workaround works to skip error returned, but the excel doc remains opened and the changes are not saved.

Comment: Open sheet with $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open( $path, [System.Type]::Missing, $false )

Comment: Ok Ansgar tried this 




but excel remains opened and saves not changed.

( i will update the code in the post)

Thanks, BR.

Comment: I'm not Ansgar. :)

Comment: Sorry for the confussion f6a4!! ;) i have updated the post.
Thanks! BR.

Answer (score 0):

This is working here without any problems:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible       = $True
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False 

$workbook            = $excel.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Users\myName\Desktop\testexcel.xlsx", [System.Type]::Missing, $false ) 

[void]$workbook.Save()
[void]$workbook.Close() 
[void]$excel.Quit() 

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Hi again f6a4!! sorry but even the code works great, the excel window with the excel doc remains opened and won't close then the changes are not saved. I am really angry :( :( . thank you very much !!.